# Request Time Out on Ruby on Rails with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, heroku

My fairly complex job board app seems to suffer from time outs and memory errors - I get messages such as the below daily from my log provider:

```
Apr 25 20:22:47 site-production heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/jobs?job_id=66565&show=true" host=www.site.de request_id=b716c55f-22c8-4255-b83d-2e25a1d0a018 fwd="80.248.226.4" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
Apr 25 20:22:54 site-production heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/jobs?job_id=403912&show=true" host=www.site.de request_id=04837f2e-1801-4e74-ae5d-237bceab4711 fwd="193.181.19.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
Apr 25 20:23:00 site-production heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/jobs?job_id=178320&show=true" host=www.site.de request_id=27ad986d-2ddc-427e-aeb0-9a209c393494 fwd="185.139.164.53" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
Apr 25 20:23:02 site-production heroku/router: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/jobs?jobsearch_id=172059&page=1" host=www.site.de request_id=e01a5f8e-7f86-4d86-a4f3-973a8f40aae8 fwd="176.74.196.127" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

I'm thinking about the best approach for how to analyse and tackle this. It seems related to my high memory usage (133%) and slow/complex queries.

Please critizise my approach:

1. Identify the slowest / most resource intensive queries (NewRelic, then learn how to fix them - Elasticsearch?)
2. Look for most memory intensive parts of the app (search guides re memory on RoR, then optimize)
3. Clean up gem file/update - remove non-required gems
4. Review app with external dev for second opinion
5. Sleep better

Happy to get feedback or ideas - currently running 3 professional 2x dynos on Heroku and app still feels very slow. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would approach this:

1. I always start with the Heroku documentation on [the error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout).
2. Look at [expensive queries](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/expensive-queries) by running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.
3. Look at [caching](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers).
4. And yes, Elasticsearch for all things search. It's ridiculously fast and can really take the stress out of your main application.

Answer (score 1):

Run the complex or longer job in background using deplayed_job gem beacuse heroku throw request timeout if any request takes more than 30 secs.

Comment: Thank you. I have some workers that run via sidekiq and handle the most complex stuff (importing jobs from xml files). I guess the longest queries will be job searches, and those have to be done asap.